# In struts2, is it possible to use optional patternMapping with variable?

Tags: java, struts2

constant

```
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex" />
```

current version

```
<action name="list/{pageNo}" method="list" class="xx.GroupAction">
    <result type="dispatcher">/WEB-INF/jsp/sys/group/list.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="list">
    <result type="redirectAction">list/</result>
</action>
```

this is what I want

```
<action name="list(/{pageNo})?" method="list" class="xx.GroupAction">
    <result type="dispatcher">/WEB-INF/jsp/sys/group/list.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Introduced from [wildcard-mappings](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html)

It is possible to achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The documentation link you provided explains the options available. Optional matching and parenthesis are not features of wildcard-mappings.